# How to show a notice, when something in the backend database has changed in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an activity timeline. The data is coming from a MySQL database via PHP and is shown via Ajax in the HTML page. Now I want to display a notice to the user via jQuery or JavaScript, that something has added in the database, and he can refresh with a simple button press.

An example is in Stackoverflow, when someone has added a comment or an answer. Or in twitter, when new tweets are available.

Does someone have some experience with that?

Comment: You can use websockets to solve the problem.

Comment: make javascript do a request to your php script every 5 seconds with the last ID that it got from database. Your php script needs to return -1 when there are no new tweets to save bandwidth, or return Tweet ID, Tweet content if there are new tweets.

Answer (score 1):

You can set some pre-defined time interval for the ajax call (kind of auto ajax) which check's the updated activity of the database. In response you can return the updated activity and display to user and some kind of notice like success message at top which appears for few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Angular two-way data binding.

[Two Way Data Binding In AngularJS with Directives with PHP and MySQL](http://www.discussdesk.com/two-way-data-binding-in-angularjs-with-directives.htm)